# Improvements in my python code for 'Find the Peak Element'

Tags: binary-search

A peak element is an element that is greater than its neighbors.

Given an input array where num[i] ≠ num[i+1], find a peak element and return its index.

The array may contain multiple peaks, in that case return the index to any one of the peaks is fine.

You may imagine that num[-1] = num[n] = -∞.

For example, in array [1, 2, 3, 1], 3 is a peak element and your function should return the index number 2.

```
class Solution:
# @param num, a list of integer
# @return an integer
def findPeakElement(self, num):
    if len(num)==0: return None
    if len(num)==1: return 0
    return self.findPeakHelper(num,0,len(num)-1)
def findPeakHelper(self,num,start,end):
    mid = (start+end)/2
    if mid>start and mid < end:
        if(num[mid-1]<num[mid] and num[mid]>num[mid+1]):
            return mid
        if(num[mid-1]>num[mid]):
            return self.findPeakHelper(num,start,mid)
        else:
            return self.findPeakHelper(num,mid,end)
    else:
        if num[mid]>num[mid+1]:
            return mid
        else:return mid+1
```

Comment: It should go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Yu. Will do That

Comment: why a binary search?  a binary search is only meaningful on sorted data, and you can't have a peak on sorted numbers.

Comment: Thanks @YuHao . Got the answer from stackExchange just in case anyone is interested. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79910/find-the-peak-element-using-bs